# OpenCL clEnqueueNDRangeKernel how to set work group size correctly

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL, if I want to add two N-dimension vectors, the global work group size (`globalSize`) should satisfy `globalSize = ceil(N/localSize) * localSize`, where `localSize` is the local work group size. Is this correct? If `N = 1000`, and `localSize = 128`, `globalSize` should be `1024`? Can we always set `globalSize` some multiple of `localSize` and larger than needed?

I tried many times and it worked well for 1-dimension problems.

However, when it comes to 2d problems, for example, multiply two matrices of dimension `m*n` and `n*p`, the result matrix is of order `m*p`, things get more complicated.

The max work group size on my device is `128`, so I set `localSize [2] = {16,8}` and
`globalSize [2] = {ceil(m/16)*16,ceil(p/8)*8}`.

It is similar to the 1-dimension case but the result is wrong!

If I set `localSize [2] = {1,128}` and change the `globalSize` accordingly, I can get the correct result. So where is the problem? Can anyone tell me why?

In addition, I find out the indices where the matrix element is wrong.

It seems that the result is wrong at `(i,j)` where `i*p + j = n * some constant (n = 1,2,3...)`

Why?

Here is my kernel function:

```c
kernel void mmult(const int Mdim, const int Ndim, const int Pdim,
                  global float *A, global float *B, global float *C)
{

    int i = get_global_id(1);
    int j = get_global_id(0);
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > Mdim || j > Pdim) return;
    else 
    {
        float tmp = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < Ndim; k++)
            tmp += A[i*Ndim+k] * B[k*Pdim+j];

        C[i*Pdim + j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

And then it is the host program:

```
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Use cl::vector instead of STL version
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace cl;

int main()
{
    // Create the two input matrices
    int m = 1000;
    int n = 1000;
    int p = 1000;
    float *A = new float[m*n];
    float *B = new float[n*p];
    for(int i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = i;

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n*p; i++)
    {
        B[i] = i;
    }
    try
    {
        // Get available platforms
        vector<Platform> platforms;
        Platform::get(&platforms);

        // Select the default platform and create a context using this platform and the GPU
        cl_context_properties cps[3] =
        {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
            (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(),
            0
        };
        Context context( CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cps);

        // Get a list of devices on this platform
        vector<Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

        // Create a command queue and use the first device
        CommandQueue queue = CommandQueue(context, devices[0]);

        // Read source file
        std::ifstream sourceFile("mmul.cl");
        std::string sourceCode(
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
            (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()+1));

        // Make program of the source code in the context
        Program program = Program(context, source);

        // Build program for these specific devices

        program.build(devices);

        // Make kernel
        Kernel kernel(program, "mmult");

        // Create memory buffers
        Buffer bufferA = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, m*n * sizeof(float));
        Buffer bufferB = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, p*n * sizeof(float));
        Buffer bufferC = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, m*p * sizeof(float));

        // Copy lists A and B to the memory buffers
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferA, CL_TRUE, 0, m * n * sizeof(float), A);
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(bufferB, CL_TRUE, 0, p * n * sizeof(float), B);

        // Set arguments to kernel
        kernel.setArg(0, m);
        kernel.setArg(1, n);
        kernel.setArg(2, p);
        kernel.setArg(3, bufferA);
        kernel.setArg(4, bufferB);
        kernel.setArg(5, bufferC);

        // Run the kernel on specific ND range

        NDRange global((ceil((float)(p)/16))*16,(ceil((float)(m)/8))*8);

        NDRange local(16,8);
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, NullRange, global, local);

        // Read buffer C into a local list
        float *C = new float[m*p];
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, m*p * sizeof(float), C);


        // check the correctness of the result
        float *c = new float[m*p];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            {
                float z = 0.0;
                for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    z += A[i*n+k] * B[k*p+j];
                }
                c[i*p+j] = z;
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < m*p; i++)
        {
            if(fabs(c[i]-C[i])>0.001)
                std::cout<<i<<" "<<c[i]<<" "<<C[i]<<std::endl;
        }

        delete []A;
        delete []B;
        delete []C;
    }
    catch(Error error)
    {
        std::cout << error.what() << "(" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your kernel check the global indices to ensure they are within the correct range?

Comment: I have if conditonal check, if the indices is out of proper range, then I just let the function return without doing any calculation. Like x = get_global_id(0), y = get_global_id(1); And only x between 0 and m and y between 0 and n, then the function does its calculation, otherwise it just returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bounds checking code inside your OpenCL kernel is incorrect. Instead of this:

```
if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > Mdim || j > Pdim) return;
```

You should have this:

```
if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= Mdim || j >= Pdim) return;
```

Comment: Aha! I see. I made such a stupid mistake that troubles me for such long time!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, that you have float matrix of size 1000x1000:

```
const int size = 1000;
// Whatever
float* myMatrix = (float*)calloc(size * size, sizeof(*myMatrix));
```

Determine size of Local Group first:

```
size_t localSize[] = {16, 8};
```

Then determine, how many Local Groups do you need:

```
size_t numLocalGroups[] = {ceil(size/localSize[0]), ceil(size/localSize[1])};
```

Finally, determine NDRange size:

```
size_t globalSize[] = {localSize[0] * numLocalGroups[0], localSize[1] * numLocalGroups[1]};
```

Don't forget to handle out-of-bounds access in right-most Local Groups.

Comment: My code is almost exactly like yours, but I still get wrong results. Only localSize[] = {1,128} can do. The out-of-bounds access is already handled. Perhaps I should paste my code in my question.

Comment: You're not using local groups in your kernel. Why are you setting them explicitly in your Host code?

Comment: If I don't set local size and leave it as a NULL value, the program will automatically select certain local size which is usually not optimal. In 1-dimensional case, if I set localSize as NULL, the program will be much slower than localSize = 128.

Comment: Did you try? What are the numbers to compare?

Comment: Yes. If N = 1000 in 1d case, the automatically selected localSize is quite slow and it becomes much faster if I set localSize = 128. I think the localSize should be as large as possible, otherwise we'll have more work groups. Because work group number is always larger than computing units, so more group count leads to longer execution time.